# Maven - Missing archetype in STS (Eclipse) for Oracle Coherence

Tags: maven, oracle-coherence

I am trying to follow this tutorial to develop an Oracle Coherence project in Maven:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/coherence_project.htm#MAVEN8911

I have installed in my Spring Tool Suit (Eclipse) the following plugin:

**Oracle Coherence Tools**
Tools for developing applications for Oracle Coherence.  These features are also part of Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE)

But when I try to create a Maven project, in the list Archetypes I can't find 
any with groupID = com.oracle.coherence

Anyone could tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

due to oracle coherence is not in the public maven repository. you should first install the coherence to your local maven repository or use the oracle maven repository instead

Comment: $ mvn install:install-file  \
      -DgroupId=com.oracle.coherence  \
      -DartifactId=coherence  \
      -Dversion=12.1.2-0-1  \
      -Dfile=coherence.jar  \
      -Dpackaging=jar \
      -DgeneratePom=true

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Coherence Tools are not such important. You can use standard Eclipse or Netbeans, IntelliJ... The most important (as xukai mentioned) is to insatll coherence and add dependency to coherence.jar in your pom.